# How to create a Day/Hour heatmaps using Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, heatmap, data-analysis

I am trying to create heatmap calculating the traffic to our store based on the transaction data that I have.

```
   buyId     date      time        weekday
0    1     2021-03-11  09:03:24    Saturday
1    2     2021-03-13  12:03:24    Friday
2    3     2021-03-09  20:03:24    Monday
3    4     2021-03-13  15:03:24    Tuesday
4    5     2021-03-07  10:03:24    Thursday
5    6     2021-03-10  13:03:24    Monday

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.imshow(df['weekday'], df['time'].values,'.')
plt.show()
```

I want to create heatmap looks like this using Python. I am using Matplotlib but couldn't able to do it yet. Can anyone help me with this?
[image]

Comment: Please attach your code with sample data and visualization. Also explain what exactly does not work.

Comment: Just added the code